# Finding $\int e^{(\ln x + x)} \ dx$.

Tags: calculus, integration

I need some help with finding the indefinite integral of: $ e^{(\ln x + x)}$. Originally, I thought that it would come out to be: $\frac{e^(lnx + x)}{\frac{1}{x} + 1}$. But I looked online, and it says the integral is actually: $e^x(x - 1)$. Thank you in advance.

Comment: $e^{\ln x + x} = x.e^x$ (!!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $e^{\log x + x} = xe^x$. Now integrate it by parts.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: for $x > 0$, $e^{\ln(x)} = x$. Then
$$\int e^{\ln(x)+x}\text{ d}x = \int e^{\ln(x)}e^{x}\text{ d}x = \int xe^{x}\text{ d}x\text{.}$$